# Implicitly typed local variables must be initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is the Code :- 
How to initialize the `data`?

```
var data;

if (mode == "view")
                {
                    data = (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
                            where a.CompanyId == companyId
                            join b in ctx.tblTO_ShiftSchedule on a.Id equals b.EmployeeId
                            where b.CompanyId == companyId                            
                            select new { a, b, c, d }).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    data = (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
                            where a.CompanyId == companyId                            
                            select new { a, b, c, d }).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: You can't do that. `var` must be initialized when it is created. Meaning `var data = yourlinqexpression;` The fact that two anonymous types *look* the same (have a,b,c,d) does not make them the same. You can't use one variable to hold both. If you want to do that, declare a typed class.

Comment: If you must define it like that, use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: the `var` keyword just tells the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the right side of the assignment expression. In your code, the statement `var data;` isn't assigning anything to `data` and therefore the compiler can not infer the type and you get a compile time error.

Comment: @dman: Your statemant *"The fact that two anonymous types look the same (have a,b,c,d) does not make them the same. You can't use one variable to hold both."* is false. Its perfectly fine to use the conditional operator to let the compiler resolve both linq expressions to one compatible anonymous type `new { a, b, c, d}`.

Comment: @InBetween - I stand corrected. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can't initialize anonymous type, so:

```
var data = mode == "view" 
? (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
                        where a.CompanyId == companyId
                        join b in ctx.tblTO_ShiftSchedule on a.Id equals b.EmployeeId
                        where b.CompanyId == companyId                            
                        select new { a, b, c, d }).ToList()
: (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
                        where a.CompanyId == companyId                            
                        select new { a, b, c, d }).ToList();
```

Comment: You *can* initialize an anonymous typed variable, but it is not pretty.

Comment: This doesn't compile, there's an extra semicolon.

Comment: i removed... it's oblivious fix

Answer (score 0):

The variables c and d (and b in the second part) in your query are not defined, so I am somewhat guessing at what you want do achieve. Hence my code is not complete.

You need a helper method:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetDefaultEnumerable<T>(T instance)
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then initialize data with a dummy object of the anonymous type

```
var data = GetDefaultEnumerable(new { a = new tblEmployee(), b = new tblTO_ShiftSchedule(), c = ..., d = ... });
```

However, in most cases it should be clearer with using a normal type. If possible, you might also consider refactoring the condition into the query.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Initialize an Anonymous type
If your are aware of the structure you would get from your linq query i would suggest you to create a Named Structure
For example

```
class Data
{
    Public Property A {get; set;}
    Public Property B {get; set;}
    Public Property C {get; set;}
    Public Property D {get; set;}
}
```

and modify your existing code to look like this

```
var data = List<Data>;

if (mode == "view")
{
    data = (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
           where a.CompanyId == companyId
           join b in ctx.tblTO_ShiftSchedule on a.Id equals b.EmployeeId
           where b.CompanyId == companyId                            
           select new Data with { A=a, B=b, C=c, D=d }).ToList();
}
else
{
    data = (from a in ctx.tblEmployee
            where a.CompanyId == companyId                            
            select new Data with { A=a, B=b, C=c, D=d }).ToList();
}
```